# Compiler seems to ignore type bound in type refinement

Tags: scala, type-inference, path-dependent-type, type-bounds

The type refinement in the code below seems to say that the path-dependent type `vt.ValueT` includes `this.type`:

```
trait ValueType {
  type ValueT <: Value

  type ConstrainedT <: ConstrainedValue

  def makeConstrainedValue(v: ValueT): ConstrainedT = ???
}

trait Value {
  type ValueTypeT <: ValueType { type ValueT >: this.type } // <--- HEY, COMPILER, READ THIS

  val vt: ValueTypeT

  def asConstrainedValue = vt.makeConstrainedValue(this) // <--- Compiler complains here
}

trait ConstrainedValue { /* details omitted */ }
```

but the Scala compiler (version 2.11.2) says:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Value.this.type (with underlying type Test.Value)
required: Value.this.vt.ValueT
   override def asConstrainedValue = vt.makeConstrainedValue(this)
                                                             ^
```

Is there some reason why deducing that `this.type <: vt.ValueT` is illegitimate here? Is there another way to tell the compiler what it needs to know?

I've tried putting the type refinement on the declaration of `vt`. The compiler objects that the resulting type is [volatile](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#volatile-types). Perhaps that's a clue to the problem.

The refinement `{ type ValueT = this.type }` generates the same error message.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is that in the bound `>: this.type`, the binding for `this` gets muddled somehow by the compiler. If I make the following changes (& remove `override` from `asConstrainedValue`), compilation succeeds for me:

```
trait Value { self =>
  type ValueTypeT <: ValueType { type ValueT >: self.type }
  …
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! Do you think there might be a reason why `self =>` is needed here?

Comment: I really don't know, sorry.

Comment: Ah, I think I just figured it out: `this` inside the type refinement refers to the `ValueTypeT` object, not the `Value` object.